# Pickling error while using pool.map in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I have a function which is as follows:

```
def func1(date1,date2):
 #calculations

if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    dates = [[dt.datetime(2016,6,17),dt.datetime(2016,6,23)],[dt.datetime(2016,6,24),dt.datetime(2016,6,30)],[dt.datetime(2016,7,1),dt.datetime(2016,7,7)],[dt.datetime(2016,7,8),dt.datetime(2016,7,14)]]
    result=pool.map(lambda x: func1(x),dates)
```

I see below error:

```
    File "Location_Factors_C.py", line 204, in <module>
    result=pool.map(lambda x: func1(x),dates)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my function to accept a list of dates :

```
def func1(datelist):
   date1 = datelist[0]
   date2 = datelist[1]


if __name__=='__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    dates = [[dt.datetime(2016,6,17),dt.datetime(2016,6,23)],[dt.datetime(2016,6,24),dt.datetime(2016,6,30)],[dt.datetime(2016,7,1),dt.datetime(2016,7,7)],[dt.datetime(2016,7,8),dt.datetime(2016,7,14)]]
    result=pool.map(func1,dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you need an asterisk

```
result=pool.map(lambda x: func1(x),dates)
```

should be:

```
result=pool.map(lambda x: func1(*x),dates)
```

You have func1() needing 2 arguments and you are only passing a single list in.

Comment: still the same error:

           cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed

Comment: you may need to put in your function then.